# Horizontal equivalent to \raisebox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes

Is there a horizontal equivalent to `\raisebox`?  I'd like to shift some content horizontally without altering the layout of surrounding content.

**Edit:**

I feel bad because my question wasn't precise enough.  David Carlisle's answer is the best if you're looking for the true horizontal analogue to `\raisebox` (moves content horizontally instead of vertically, operates in vertical mode instead of LR mode).  However, what I really want is something that works in LR mode.

Comment: @RichardHansen: You could do `\hspace*{<length>}\mbox{<content>}\hspace{-<length>}`

Comment: BTW, LaTeX is the default here, so you don't have to mentioned it. For other things like plainTeX there is a special tag.

Comment: @MartinScharrer:  Feel free to add that as an answer.  :)  How does it compare to Werner's answer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a macro `\shifttext{<len>}{<stuff>}` that shifts `<stuff>` by `<len>` (negative for left, positive for right):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\shifttext}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#2}%
  \makebox[\@tempdima]{\hspace*{#1}#2}%
}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
Here is some text. \par
Here is \shifttext{20pt}{some} text. \par
Here is \shifttext{-20pt}{some} text. \par
\end{document}
```

Note that, in its current form, the shifted content shouldn't contain any `\label` or counter content. However, that can be fixed if needed, by boxing the content first.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it seems like the simplest, it works in LR mode, and it contains an illustration.  But the other answers are excellent too.  Too bad I can't accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 31):

If you are in a vertical context you can use the primitive `moveright`

```
\moveright  2in  \hbox{.....}
```

Comment: Never heard about `\moveright`. You never stop learning!

Comment: @MartinScharrer: It's very rarely used. LaTeX2e uses it in _one_ place (outputting the page headers); L3 nowhere yet. Even ConTeXt doesn't use it.

Comment: Is there something like this that works in horizontal mode and is already defined in TeX/LaTeX?  Or do I have to make my own macro/use a 3rd party package to do it?

Comment: @RichardHansen in horizontal mode you can just go \hspace{1in}\mbox{hello}\hspace{-1in}  `\moveright` is the natural analogue of `\raisebox` which is defined in terns of `\raise` which works exactly the same way (with the same syntax) as `\moveright` but in hmode rather than vmode.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is using `\hspace` is definitely preferred over using `\hspace*` for this purpose?

Comment: no star form would be better despite my comment above, so it works at start of line. Conversly the star form isnt needed if you are already in an hmox, as in the accepted answer. It does no harm to use the star there though:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : (Sorry for the necropost.  But I'm wrestling this problem now as well.)  `\hspace` is not equivalent/sufficient since it alters the placement of *preceding* text.  MWE: `\documentclass[letterpaper]{extarticle} \usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage{blindtext} \begin{document} \begin{flushright} \raisebox{0.14in}{Names:} \rule[-0.05in]{0.25pt}{0.5in}\rule[-0.05in]{2in}{0.1pt}  \hspace{-1.1in}\raisebox{0.14in}{Solutions}\hspace{1.1in} \end{flushright} (Where is that right margin?)\\ \blindtext \end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I don't have a new question.  I merely dispute your comment: "you can just go \hspace{1in}\mbox{hello}\hspace{-1in}".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Wrapping in `\mbox{}` has no effect.  Changing the following to `\hspace*` leaves uncontrollable right margin.  In short, the `\hspace` solution does not (analogously) "return the insertion point to the position it had prior to the negative `\hspace`".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : If we got back where we started, the horizontal rule wouldn't spill into the right margin.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : This also fails.  Contrast with: Delete "`\hspace{-1.1in}\raisebox{0.14in}{Solutions}\hspace{1.1in}\mbox{}`" from your very last comment.  According to your first `\hspace` comment, The undeleted version should be identical to the deleted version except for the word "Solutions" bloating in the space bounded by the rules.  If the rules move, the insertion point has moved.  If the right margin is measured from the end of the word "Solutions" (with or without the positive trailing `\hspace`), then `hspace` has not done what you say it does.

Comment: @EricTowers no sorry it is impossibe to discuss in comments  with white-space mangled code examples. As I said above (comments since cleaned up)  open a question if there is still an issue.

Answer (score 24):

My `adjustbox` package provides `\lapbox[<width>]{<amount>}{<content>}` which is a generalization of `\rlap{<content>}` and `\llap{<content>}`, but can also be used as horizontal equivalent of `\raisebox`. The `<amount>` can be positive or negative and will move the content to the right or left, respectively. The original width can be accessed as `\width`. The official width can be set manually, otherwise it is reduced by the lap amount.

As always there is also a key equivalent for `\adjustbox{<key=value>}{<content>}` called `lap` in this case.

#### Excerpt from the `adjustbox` manual about `\lapbox`:

> This macro is a generalisation of the LaTeX core macros `\rlap{<content>}` and `\llap{<content>}` which lap the text to the right or left without taking any official space. The `\lapbox` macro can be used to only partially lap the content to the right (positive amount) or left (negative amount). As with all macros of this package the original width can be references using `\width`. The resulting official width of the box is normally the original width minus the absolute lap amount. However, it can also be set explicitly using the option argument. It is also possible to use lap amount which absolute values are larger than the original width. In this case the resulting official width will
>   be zero by default and the content will padded with the required white space. Note that the lap amount always states the distance between the right side of the official box and the right side of the actual content for positive amounts or the distance between the left side of the official box and the left side of the actual content for negative values.

See the manual for graphical examples.

#### Example:

If you want to move some content 1em to the right without changing its official width, use:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% ...
\lapbox[\width]{1em}{Some text}
% or
\adjustbox{lap={\width}{1em}}{Some text}
```

The `\adjustbox` version can also be combined with other keys like `raise`, which is the equivalent of `\raisebox`.

Comment: `adjustbox` is definitely the coolest package.

Answer (score 14):

I figured out just another simple alternative, that consists of two boxes, one aligned left and the other right.

```
\newcommand{\shiftleft}[2]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}}
\newcommand{\shiftright}[2]{\makebox[#1][r]{\makebox[0pt][l]{#2}}}
```

example:

```
\shiftright{20pt}{text}
```

Shifts 'text' to the right.

Comment: Very nice, and much easier to get working than the other answers.  Thank you