# shifting and overlapping characters

Tags: fonts, graphics, formatting, positioning

(Sorry, if this q. is not appropriate).

I used to know how to shift "m" sideways a little, then I would overlap the original and the shifted "m". This way I got a 4-legged "m" instead of the standard 3-legged "m". Could you explain how to obtain this kind of an effect, i.e. how to:

1. shift a character;
2. overlap two or more characters.

I think that everybody would be overjoyed with this kind of skills.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Horizontal equivalent to `\raisebox`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51113/5764)

Comment: Welcome! `I think that everybody would be overjoyed ...`. You are surely not British. :-)

Comment: @cfr - I am guilty as charged. How could I make myself sound a bit more English in my post?

Comment: You don't want to sound English - good grief! Your English is fine. It is just that the British are well-known for the understatement, whereas you seem to be a master of the overstatement. (Or you have led a sadly deprived life. Or both, of course. But I'm betting on the overstatement.) Don't worry: Americans will think it perfectly normal ;).

Comment: This is, of course, the kind of national stereotyping which one should not engage in. But, it is safer when I'm among the targeted parties :(. (Besides, I seriously doubt anybody would object to this one as it is pretty harmless and not really objectionable, as far as I can tell.)

Comment: Could you tell us what you need this for? Is a 4-legged (non)-m just an example or is this a special character which you're trying to imitate? I ask because the best solution is going to depend on how you want to use it and how much stuff of what kind is being shifted around.

Comment: Off-topic: note that British \neq English. You mustn't forget the Celtic nations: the Welsh and Scottish are also British, but definitely not English!

Comment: @Werner - thank you for your answer, and for directing me to the respective thread. I have G.Gratzer's *Math into $\LaTeX$* where I was able to find shifting+overlapping easily years ago; though, with your help, I can combine the textbook and the thread.

Comment: ( @cfr - needless to say, I was joking).

Comment: Indeed. As was I. But it is dangerous to joke that we Celts are English. There's a history here ....

Comment: @cfr - I live dangerously I guess. I'll write about my LaTeX needs under the StevenBSegletes' Answer below.

Comment: How come $\LaTeX$ nor $\TeX$ don't compile here? Will $\ 1+2^3 = 3^2\ $ ?

Answer (score 3):

Since neither of these approaches was mentioned on the other thread cited by Werner, I'll show them here.  The first is with `\ooalign` and the second with `\stackengine`.

Obviously, for the case of a 4-legged "m", there are additional issues with the serif; however, I gather the question was more of one asking for techniques rather than a particular-looking result.

Both methods (particularly `\stackengine`) allow for vertical and horizontal offsets, various alignments, etc. and thus are capable of more versatility than what you have requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
a\ooalign{m\cr\kern2.7pt m}bc

a\stackengine{0pt}{m}{\kern2.7pt m}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}bc
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, however, the appearance of a 4-legged "m" were the important thing, then it can be accomplished by clipping off the left part of the serifed "m", and kerning a bit more to compensate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\begin{document}
a\ooalign{m\cr\kern4.7pt \clipbox{2pt 0pt 0pt -1pt}{m}}bc
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @StevenBSeglets - thank you. I'll see if TeXShop on my Mac can handle \usepackage. (I am a poor computer user, and Mac/Apple is nasty). *** Since 1985, I was developing my language *dabanese*, and then a universal database *daba*. Thus it'd be nice to create whole bunches of new characters for my *daba+dabanese*.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński `\usepackage{}` is core LaTeX. However, if you are looking to typeset a new language, you really need to create a font containing the characters you need.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński If `\usepackage` proves unsuccessful for your installation, the `\ooalign` approach (without clipping) should be possible without additional packages.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - I'll follow your advice, will let you know (I might be slow though).

Comment: @cfr - if I had the software capacity... Anyway, I have everything needed but, due to my limitations, I haven't developed much of the body of the language. The number of dabagrams (dabanese ideograms) is potentially infinite. The language will be under a strict control (first by me, then by a committee) but there would be additional extensions for different domains. They'd be slowly accepted/adapted (a bit at the time) by the official dabanese. At this time, besides $\TeX$ mathematical symbols, I am using mostly pigeon dabagrams (3 to 4 characters of English and Polish abbreviations).